# When to use viertel vor sechs and when to use drei viertel sechs?

Tags: learning, time

I am a German language beginner. I understand that, in principle, the time 17:45 could be referred to (informally, unofficially) as either "Viertel vor sechs" ("a quarter to six") or "dreiviertel sechs" ("three quarters [...] six") and that the latter is less common and only used in some parts of Germany and Austria.

How common in practice is this latter (and to an English native speaker, very confusing) form and in which parts of the German-speaking world can I expect to encounter it?

By extension, does "viertel sechs" (without the "vor") mean 17:15 in these parts of the world?

Comment: To the last part: yes, "viertel sechs" is 17:15. "halb sechs (halb = zwei viertel)" is 17:30, "dreiviertel sechs" is 17:45. Very easy ;-)...

Comment: I found [this map](http://www.norddeutschelernendieuhrzulesen.de/geo/) but can't assess the reliability.

Comment: As a help for people wanting to answer: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/uhrzeit/ http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f11e/

Comment: Statt 5 nach halb 6 kann man auch 7 zwölftel 6 sagen. Analog ist 1 drittel 6 auch 20 nach 5.

Comment: "and to an English native speaker, very confusing" - thinking about the actual meaning of the words *is* confusing (also for a German native speaker). It only becomes clear once you realize that in that system, "the current hour" is "something that gets gradually completed". "Es ist viertel sechs." says that a quarter of the hour no. 6 has been completed." More literally: "It is six o'clock (we are within the sixth hour), but it is not completely six o'clock yet, just one quarter of it so far."

Comment: Actually "dreiviertel sechs" is more common…

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here are trying to make things far more complicated than they need be for a beginner.

> viertel nach fünf
>   halb sechs
>   viertel vor sechs

will be understood **everywhere** in the German-speaking world

> viertel sechs
>   dreiviertel sechs

are likely to cause confusion in large parts of the German-speaking world

Answer (score 3):

I live in Austria (first 30 years in Graz, then 20 years in Vienna and now for 2 years in St. Pölten).

Here *»dreiviertel sechs«* is much more common than *»viertel vor sechs«*. But, as you already know, this differs from region to region. I have not much idea how big the *dreiviertel*-area really is, and where it overlaps with the *Viertel-vor*-region.

This is how we in Austria tell the time. There are always more than one possibilities, I write them one below the other. Those which are used not very often are put in brackets:

- **17:00**
  siebzehn Uhr
  fünf Uhr
  fünf
- **17:05**
  siebzehn Uhr fünf
  fünf nach fünf
- **17:10**
  siebzehn Uhr zehn
  zehn nach fünf
  (fünf vor viertel sechs)
- **17:15**
  siebzehn Uhr fünfzehn
  viertel sechs
  (viertel nach fünf)
  (viertel über fünf)
- **17:20**
  siebzehn Uhr zwanzig
  fünf nach viertel sechs
  zehn vor halb sechs
- **17:25**
  siebzehn Uhr fünfundzwanzig
  fünf vor halb sechs
- **17:30**
  siebzehn Uhr dreißig
  halb sechs
- **17:35**
  siebzehn Uhr fünfunddreißig
  fünf nach halb sechs
- **17:40**
  siebzehn Uhr vierzig
  zehn nach halb sechs
  fünf vor dreiviertel sechs
- **17:45**
  siebzehn Uhr fünfundvierzig
  dreiviertel sechs
- **17:50**
  siebzehn Uhr fünfzig
  zehn vor sechs
  (fünf nach dreiviertel sechs)
- **17:55**
  siebzehn Uhr fünfundfünfzig
  fünf vor sechs
- **18:00**
  achtzehn Uhr
  sechs Uhr
  sechs

Comment: Ah, genau derselbe Gedanke. Es geht ja nicht nur um *dreiviertel*.
.

Comment: *fünf vor/nach viertel/dreiviertel* scheint eine österreichische Spezialität zu sein.

Comment: @Janka Das kenne ich aus Ostdeutschland auch

Comment: Bei 18:00 Uhr fehlt noch "viertel vor viertel nach sechs".

Answer (score 3):

> When to use viertel vor sechs and when to use drei viertel sechs?

Simple answer: As a foreigner you should never do this.

The reason is simple:

> ... and that the latter is ... only used in some parts of Germany and Austria.

... and I was told that the second form is **not even understood** by people coming from some parts of Germany!

However the first form is understood and used all over Germany.

> How common in practice is this latter ... form

In south-western Germany it is very, very common. (However there are also people using the first form.)

> By extension, does "viertel sechs" mean 17:15 ...

Yes, but ...

> ... in these parts of the world?

... the map linked in Pharguin's answer shows that the regions where the term "dreiviertel sechs" is used and the regions where "viertel sechs" is used are **not** identical.

Answer (score 3):

Simply to complete all other answers I want add the following resource.
The site "Atlas der Deutschen Sprache" is referencing an old map of the usage spread over Germany, Austria and Switzerland. In general there is no rule when to use which.

This might also be worth reading:

http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f11e/

[image]

Comment: Of course, Atlas der Deutschen Sprache usually just points out which alternative most people in each region would be most likely to use. It does not provide any insight into which alternatives they understand.

Answer (score 1):

In German, there are many common ways to tell the clock, that makes it a bit complicated.

> 16:55 – fünf vor fünf (nachmittags) **oder** sechzehn Uhr fünfundfünfzig
>
> 17:00 – (um) fünf **oder** fünf Uhr (nachmittags) **oder** siebzehn Uhr
>
> 17:15 – viertel nach fünf (nachmittags) **oder** viertel sechs (abends) **oder** siebzehn Uhr fünfzehn
>
> 17:20 – zehn vor halb sechs (abends) **oder** siebzehn Uhr zwanzig
>
> 17:30 – halb sechs (abends) **oder** siebzehn Uhr dreißig
>
> 17:35 – fünf nach halb sechs (abends) **oder** siebzehn Uhr fünfunddreißig
>
> 17:45 – viertel vor sechs (abends) **oder** *dreiviertel* sechs (abends) **oder** siebzehn Uhr fünfundvierzig

All of these are universally used and understood, as you may encounter German speakers from any region anywhere throughout Germany, Austria and Switzerland.

Swiss German uses **ab** instead of **nach**, Austrian German **über** instead of **nach**. These aren't universally understood.

Your question was specifically about the **dreiviertel sechs**. This is common in most of East Germany, Franconia and Swabia.

Comment: In my experience, the "viertel/dreiviertel sechs" is *not* understood by many of the "viertel nach/vor" speakers, while it is understood the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

#### Origin of the term "dreiviertel 6":

To end up with your wanted time, just take the minutes of the current hour and convert it to parts of an hour. Afterwards simply add the incoming hour after it and you'll end up with someting like this:

- 17:**45** + **18**:00 Uhr (45 Minuten = drei-viertel Stunde -> *'dreiviertel 6'*)

in the same way:

- 14:**15** + **15**:00 Uhr (15 Minuten = viertel Stunde -> *'viertel 3'*)

and the most common one:

- 15:**30** + **16**:00 Uhr (30 Minuten = halbe Stunde -> *'halb 4'*)

#### Where is it used?

Nowadays mostly:

- Austria
- Bavaria
- South Tyrol

These three have a lot in common as they speak the same language (yes it can be defined as a language -> [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_language)/[Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte))
It's also used in:

- Baden-Württemberg
- Eastern Germany

#### Should I used it as a foreigner/language learner?

**That's up to you!**
It's probably easier to just go for the more widely understood "viertel vor 6", as everybody knows it and you can't go wrong with it.
**But**, if you're planning on spending most of your time in the souther parts, people will probably be pleasantly surprised as they realize you're interested in their regional culture and peculiarities. Or maybe you just want to teach some of the other Germans some math ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the already complete answers (both is correct, there are regional preferences), there exist maps to these preferences, showing which variant is more common in a specific area. Take this as an example:

http://www.zeit.de/2012/21/Deutschlandkarte-Uhrzeit